# Comparing a CustomType through ==

Tags: c#, .net

I'm pretty sure this is a basic question but for some reason i can't find it on Google as quick as I'd like so I'll ask it here.

I've got a MoneyType object, which holds an int (value in cents) and a decimal (just the normal value)

This type inherits the IComperable interface and can be compared, now i'm comparing two MoneyTypes in an If statement:

```
if (invoice.GrossAmount == invoice.NetAmount)
{
 //Something
}
```

Now for what method should i override or what interface should i inherit to get this to work? Since doing this does not enter the CompareTo() method, neither does it enter the .Equals method so I'm at a loss atm.

Comment: No, just IComparable, normally. Trying the generic version (which i did not know existed) now. edit: no dice :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you implement `IComparable`, than you implement the `CompareTo` method. Based on this implementation, testing two amounts for equality is performed as:

```
if (invoice.GrossAmount.CompareTo(invoice.NetAmount) == 0)//the $ame amount of money
{..}
```

Comparing directly with "==" means overloading the "==" operator as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28VS.71%29.aspx). That is add the following method inside the `MoneyType` class:

```
public static bool operator ==(MoneyType x, MoneyType y) 
{
      return x.CompareTo(y.NetAmount) == 0;//make use of the working IComparable implementation
}
```

You must implement "!=", too. You should also implement the Equals method (simply call the == operator) and the `GetHashCode`.

HTH,
Lucian

Comment: You're correct, one thing i am wondering though, if you do a >= comparison does it use CompareTo or do i need to define Operators there aswell. Checked myself, need to override the other operators aswell if i want to use > and <. Gues Overriding only the CompareTo methods allows for IList.Sort() functionality

Comment: No, it does not use this operator. There is no internal wiring assuring such a behavior. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=VS.71%29.aspx and see the final comment: "Note   The comparison operators, if overloaded, must be overloaded in pairs; that is, if == is overloaded, != must also be overloaded. The reverse is also true, and similar for < and >, and for <= and >=."

Answer (score 3):

MSDN:

> By default, the operator == tests for
>   reference equality by determining
>   whether two references indicate the
>   same object.

To change this you'll have to overload == and != operators. You can have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx) for the full explanation and example on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

You  must override the `==` and `!=` operator either.

```
public static bool operator ==(Invoice left, Invoice right)
{
    return Equals(left, right);
}

public static bool operator !=(Invoice left, Invoice right)
{
    return !Equals(left, right);
}
```

Implementing `IComaprable` is done in the case of **Sort**ing list of objects of that type, and **Order**ing them not *Equality*.

Answer (score 1):

Try including the following in the MoneyType class

```
        public static bool operator ==( MoneyType a, MoneyType b)
        {
            return a.cents == b.cents;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(MoneyType a, MoneyType b)
        {
            return a.cents != b.cents;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `if (invoice.GrossAmount.Equals(invoice.NetAmount))` which is perfectly acceptable.